# Why cant I see my debug logs from anonymous window

Tags: apex, controller, query, execute-anonymous, debug-logs

I have this piece of code which I like to test from the anonymous window. I aded a static Id from the org.

> Why do my debugs return empty?

here is my code in the anonymous window:

```
 public static String getLoggedInUser(){
    User ContactUser =[SELECT Id, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id ='000000000000000' LIMIT 1];
    system.debug('test1');
    Profiel__c currentUser = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id from Contacts__r WHERE Id=:Contactuser.ContactId) FROM Profiel__c][0];
    if(currentUser.Id!= null){
        system.debug('currentUser.Id '+ currentUser.Id);
        return currentUser.Id;
    }else{
        return 'NULL';
    }
}
```

Comment: At the bottom of the anonymous window, you have a checkbox "Open Log". You can click on it before your run to open the log generated by your code. Then, if you want to only see your debug statements, you can check the "Debug Only" checkbox at the bottom of the log page.

Comment: Function its self is not executing because there is calling function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not made any call for the function execution. Just defining function body will not execute the function.  You need to define a function call.
Just you need call the function **getLoggedInUser()** after the your function body.

```
public static String getLoggedInUser(){
   // same as above 
 }
 getLoggedInUser();
```

**Or**

Just run the code no need of method while running in  anonymous window.

```
User ContactUser =[SELECT Id, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id ='000000000000000' LIMIT 1];
    system.debug('test1');
    Profiel__c currentUser = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id from Contacts__r WHERE Id=:Contactuser.ContactId) FROM Profiel__c][0];
    if(currentUser.Id!= null){
        system.debug('currentUser.Id '+ currentUser.Id);    
    }else{
         system.debug('currentUser.Id = null ');
    }
```

> If you selected **Open Log**, the log will automatically open in the Log Inspector. After the code executes, the debug log will be listed on the Logs tab. Double-click the log to open it in the Log Inspector.

Comment: @jenssen Your welcome...

Answer (score 1):

When we run the code in anonymous window we don't need to make any method.

This will also work

```
User ContactUser =[SELECT Id, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id ='000000000000000' LIMIT 1];
    system.debug('test1');
    Profiel__c currentUser = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id from Contacts__r WHERE Id=:Contactuser.ContactId) FROM Profiel__c][0];
    if(currentUser.Id!= null){
        system.debug('currentUser.Id '+ currentUser.Id);
    }
```

And open the debug log and you will see the debug.